# React reference for third party html tag

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I'm looking for a way to add appearing animations with useInView hook. The problem is that I don't have the tag  that I need in my code, I get it from third party Ghost as one single tag via dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.post.html}}/>`

Is there any way to do it in React way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use web-components in JSX directly, as described in the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html#using-web-components-in-react). JSX transform should take care of it.

If you don't know the tag before compile-time there's no other way than using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.